# The constructor DbHelper(CustomListPreference) is undefined

Tags: android, listpreference

Please let me know what is wrong with the syntax. I get error 'The constructor DbHelper(CustomListPreference) is undefined'
Here my code:

CustomListPreference.java

```
public class CustomListPreference extends ListPreference {
    CustomListPreferenceAdapter customListPreferenceAdapter = null;
    Context mContext;

    private SQLiteDatabase db;
    DbHelper dbHelp = new DbHelper(this); (Here I get an error)
...
```

DbHelper.java

```
    import android.content.Context;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteOpenHelper;

public class DbHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper {
    static String DATABASE_NAME="myBase";
    public static final String KEY_NAME="name";
    public static final String KEY_ID="id";

    public DbHelper(Context context) {
        super(context, DATABASE_NAME, null, 1);
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
         db.execSQL("create table tUser ("
                  + "id integer primary key autoincrement," 
                  + "name text,"
                  + "exists integer" + ");");

    }

    @Override
    public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
        db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS "+TABLE_NAME);
        onCreate(db);

    }

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are passing `ListPreference` object whereas your DBHelper expects `Context`. See this line:

```
public DbHelper(Context context) {
        super(context, DATABASE_NAME, null, 1);
    }
```

`ListPreference` is not a child class of `Context` and hence this error. You will have revisit your design.

### Update:

You should change this line to:

```
DbHelper dbHelp = new DbHelper(mContext);
```

Comment: Please tell me how to change the design?

Comment: That is entirely upto you and what you are trying to achieve. Your question was what is wrong with the syntax and that was answered. I cannot comment on design unless I know what you are trying to do.

Comment: I want to create object and call  db = dbHelp.getReadableDatabase();